# Wordpress homepage overriding existing rules in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

**For Context:**
I am currently developing my webpage in a local environment using xampp. I have multiple domains, hence I stored each domain in its own subdirectory like so

```
htdocs
-> domain_1
-> domain_2
```

I'm having issue with 'Post Name' permalinks due to this setup, but I figured that this can be fixed by modifying certain RewriteBase and RewriteRule in the .htaccess file to account for the subdirectory.

**My issue:**
Whenever I modify the .htaccess file and launch my homepage via `localhost/domain_1`, the .htaccess is being overridden by some default setups. I have found several files related to the rewrite rules such as:

```
 - rewrite.php
 - class-wp-rewrite.php
 - developer/index.php
```

There's too many to list for what I have done with the files, but so far, no luck and my .htaccess file is still being overriden whenever I launch the homepage.
Anyone can give me a pointer to what could cause this?

Edit: here's the code for the .htaccess file.

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^.*-(\d+)/.+/$ developer/index\.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)-\d+/$ developer/index\.php?cat=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
    RewriteRule ^.*(Category[a-z]+map\.xml)$  Categorymap/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^.*(sitemap\.xml)$  Categorymap/$1 [L]

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Comment: Are your WPs actual sub-folder installations? If these are separate projects that are supposed to run under different domains in the actual live version - then you should rather try and replicate that in your dev setup, by configuring proper _virtual hosts_ for each.

Comment: If it doesn't compromise anything sensitive, I'd suggest showing what your .htaccess file looks like. Although it's entirely possible that it's not the cause, it would help people help you faster by eliminating any of the typical pitfalls people fall into. For example WordPress has a base required structure for the .htaccess, your code might conflict with that.